# Toggle HTML using a button in tampermonkey

Tags: html, tampermonkey

I have been trying to get a script working to toggle a piece of HTML when i toggle a button,
But so far i have not been able to get it working,

```
let newImg5 = document.createElement("img");
newImg5.src = "https://www.pcinvasion.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/discord.jpg";
newImg5.style = `position: absolute; bottom: 15px; left: 15px; z-index: 100000; width: 50px; height: 50px; cursor: pointer;`;
document.body.prepend(newImg5);
newImg5.addEventListener("click", () => {
       toggle.html <iframe src="https://discordapp.com/widget?id=68awdawdawdawds8&theme=dark" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
});
```

Comment: `toggle.html <iframe src="https://disc` is not valid Javascript syntax...

Comment: i know, im trying to find one that will work.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
let newImg5 = document.createElement("img");
newImg5.src = "https://www.pcinvasion.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/discord.jpg";
newImg5.style = `position: absolute; bottom: 15px; left: 15px; z-index: 100000; width: 50px; height: 50px; cursor: pointer;`;
document.body.prepend(newImg5);

/* create iframe */
let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('id', 'iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://discordapp.com/widget?id=68awdawdawdawds8&theme=dark');
iframe.setAttribute('width', '350');
iframe.setAttribute('height', '500');
iframe.setAttribute('allowtransparency', 'true');

/* Make iframe appear on click */
newImg5.addEventListener("click", () => {
       document.body.append(iframe);
});
```

Comment: Seems like most pieces work, but now the iFrame does not appear, Tried changing location of were it will append the html, but that doesnt make a diffrence either.